# How to ignore inner black contours in OpenCV python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

[image]

In the above image, I only need the following contours: 8, 7, 0, 2, 4.

Every other contour black empty boxes inside them. Is there a way to automatically extract only such contours using cv2.RETR_TREE?

cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL will ignore 2 and 4 which I actually need

```
       >>heirarchy

       >>array([[[ 7, -1,  1, -1],

        [-1, -1,  2,  0],

        [-1, -1,  3,  1],

        [-1, -1,  4,  2],

        [-1, -1,  5,  3],

        [ 6, -1, -1,  4],

        [-1,  5, -1,  4],

        [ 8,  0, -1, -1],

        [-1,  7, -1, -1]]])
```

How can I extract from the above heirarchy only the external contours but not exlcuding 2 and 4 and ignoring 1, 3, 5, 6 since those four contours contain just empty regions inside?

Comment: 5 and 6 are empty. But 1 and 3 are **not** empty. 1 contains 2 and 3 contains 4. Separating them based on hierarchy is not possible because contours 1, 2, 3, 4 have same hierarchical properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv2.contourArea(contour)` to get the area of the contour and then set a minimum area condition to get rid of too small contours.

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to use any other method than cv2.RETR_TREE , then you can use cv2.RETR_CCOMP which divides contours in only two level hierarchy i.e outer and inner. You can only pick those contours whose parent index (value at index 3) is -1. '-1' denotes that the contours do not have any parent. You will only get the following contours: 8, 7, 0, 2, 4.

Reference : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html

Comment: Hi. This is the answer that I thought too. Actually I just realised I also need contours 1 and 3. Only contours that I want to ignore is 5 and 6.

Comment: You can use the cv2.RETR_TREE method and ignore those contours which have child index (value at index 2) is '==-1' and parent index (value at index 3) is '!=-1' only from all the contours list.

Comment: This has one drawback. assume that contours 0 and 1 exist but inside there is a bunch of contours which are just filled white boxes inside 1. This will be ignored as those also do not have child but have a parent. Not only black holes will be removed but filled white contours inside rectangular box will also be removed..  I am checking if I can retain this case along with ignoring black holes

Comment: Sorry for late reply . I think you can separate filled white contours from the already separated contours by using the cv2.RETR_CCOMP. You can check the corresponding hierarchy of those contours separated by cv2.RETR_TREE in cv2.RETR_CCOMP hierarchy. White filled contours would always be a parent and will not have a child in any case in RETR_CCOMP hierarchy.